# Variable in the middle of a command, in ruby

Tags: ruby, variables, variable-assignment

I have the following code

```
require 'watir-wedriver'

browsers = ['chrome', 'safari']

browsers.each do |browserName|
    browser = Watir::Browser.new :browserName
    # more code here
end
```

`browserName` doesn’t work here since the command is interpreting it literally (i.e., it’s reading `browser = Watir::Browser.new :browserName` instead of `browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome` followed by `browser = Watir::Browser.new :safari`.

How can I make that variable expand there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't literally quote the variable

```
browsers.each do |browserName|
    browser = Watir::Browser.new browserName.to_sym # string to a symbol
    ...
 end
```

or just originally use symbols

```
 browsers = [:chrome, :safari]
 ...
     browser = Watir::Browser.new browserName
```

Comment: notice that :browserName and browserName are different things! :browserName is a symbol, and browserName is a variable.  If you want the value to change, it needs to be a variable!